# GSON mapping without entity name

Tags: android, json, object, mapping, gson

I need to map a JSON object to a class using GSON, here is the JSON object:

```
{
    "protocols": [
          [ "https", 39 ],
          [ "http", 1 ]
        ],
     ...
}
```

Generally if there are entity names specified it is easy to do something like this:

```
{
    "protocols": [
          [ "name":"https", "count":39 ],
          [ "name":"http", "count":1 ]
        ],
     ...
}

class ProtocolItem {
     @SerializedName("name")
     String protocolName;

     @SerializedName("count")
     int count;
}
```

However since no entity names are specified in this case, I am not sure how to do the mapping for this. Please point some directions for me if you are familiar with the case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike your first example,

```
[ "name":"https", "count":39 ],
```

is invalid JSON as you can either specify an array using `[1, 2]` without any names or a map using `{"x": 1, "y": 2}` with "entity names" as keys. So the solution is simple:

```
{
    "protocols": [
          [ "https", 39 ],
          [ "http", 1 ]
        ],
}
```

is a map with a single key and a value which is an array of arrays of objects. You can map it as

```
class All {
    Object[][] protocols;
}
```

You must use `Object` here, as it needs to accept both strings and ints. Instead of arrays, you can use `List`s.

I guess, you'd prefer to serialize it as

```
class All {
    Map<String, Integer> protocols;
}
```

This is possible, too, but you need a [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html). The very first linked example shows clearly how to do it (start with `beginArray`, in a loop test `JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY` and do `nextString` and `nextInt`, etc.).